# Rails if statement display 1 if both true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I have a product page and if a product has an offer on it then it displays and OFFER label, if a product is in sale then it displays a SALE label but if a product if in sale and has an offer then I only want to display the OFFER label.

#### Current View

```
<% if product.possible_promotions.any? %>
  <div data-hook="promotions" class="offer-label">
    <span>Offer</span>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if product.sale_price.present? %>
  <div class="offer-label sale-offer-label">
    <span>Sale</span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If both return true then only display the top div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically you want to exclude the bottom div unless the `sale_price` is present and `possible_promotions` is empty. Assuming `possible_promotions` is an array, then this should do it:

```
<% if product.possible_promotions.any? %>
  <div data-hook="promotions" class="offer-label">
    <span>Offer</span>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if product.sale_price.present? && product.possible_promotions.empty? %>
  <div class="offer-label sale-offer-label">
    <span>Sale</span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively you could do it in a linked if-elsif statement:

```
<% if product.possible_promotions.any? %>
  <div data-hook="promotions" class="offer-label">
    <span>Offer</span>
  </div>
<% elsif product.sale_price.present? %>
  <div class="offer-label sale-offer-label">
    <span>Sale</span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Either will work.

Another solution would be to write a helper, which accepts a product, decides what offer/sale is available and then returns the appropriate content. Then in your view you could use this:

```
<%= special_offer_for product %>
```

With a helper like this, say in your `products_helper.rb`:

```
def special_offer_for(product)
  if product.possible_promotions.any?
    render :partial => 'products/offer', :locals => { :offer_title => product.promotion }
  elsif product.sale_price.present?
    render :partial => 'products/sale', :locals => { :sale_price => product.sale_price }
  end
end
```

Put the appropriate layout/content/etc into the partials. If needs be you can pass variables into the partials using the `:locals` hash as per the example above.